# Adjust vertical axis range in tensorboard visualization

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I often encounter the following graph in tensorboard, where there is a significant drop in the first couple of iterations and much slower convergence later on.

Is there a way to adjust the vertical axis range so that I can focus on the later part to see whether it is decreasing? Alternatively, can I tell tensorboard to ignore the first few data points and auto-adjust the vertical axis for the others?

[image: tensorboard-viz]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know, aside from creating a whole new variable in your TF script, currently your only option is to **click & drag** a box around the region of interest. I found this to be slow on Firefox, but smooth on Chrome.

Comment: Actually that suits my requirement pretty well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also zoom with the ALT key + mousewheel.